# Using a string before .getName(); for c++

Tags: c++

I would like to use a string before .getName()

```
Enemy Troll(Troll, 250, 30); 

string enemyName;
enemyName = Troll;

enemyName.getName(); //this is causing the error... "No member named 'setHP' in 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'"
```

I want to be able to get the same results as using Troll.getName(); but instead use a string.

Comment: "this is causing the error" What error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: all I am trying to do is use a string on my .getName();

Comment: No member named 'setHP' in 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'

Comment: `std::string` doesn't have such a function `setHP()`? What makes you think this is related to your `getName()` function?

Comment: you are asking this in a confusing way. What you want is a mapping from "Obama" to a specific instance of the `Enemy` class. If you want that then you need to store that mapping somewhere. For example in a `std::map<std::string,Enemy>`

Comment: Alright you guys I really appreciate your time, but I have tried looking this simple question up for a while now. I just need to know how to use a string before my .getName. I do not know how to ask this in any other way.

Comment: Edit necessary info into the question.

Comment: What is "your getName"? I don't see anything like that in the code. **Complete** example please.

Comment: If SE don't allow you to post the whole code, make it a **minimal** example.

Comment: You can't use a string there because `std::string` doesn't have such a member function. Pick an item from the [C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I am sorry I knew this would confuse people. I just need to know the syntax necessary for using a string before .getName();

Comment: @MatthewHamilton it doesn't work that way, the variable name is not stored anywhere after you compile your program, you need to store and associate that yourself.

Comment: **What is `getName`?** - **Complete** example please.

Comment: If I posted the whole code it would confuse people more I think. I just need to know how to use a string before a .getName(); I feel really bad for using up everyones times. I apologize, I should ask my teacher but I doubt he will understand.

Comment: What you are asking is impossible. I think PeterT has the best guess of the real problem you are tring to solve.

Comment: That's why you should post minimal example. The smallest code that describes your issue.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton "_If I posted the whole code it would confuse people more I think._" Where did we ask to post the whole code? All we asked is for you to make [mcve].

Comment: Ok then. How do you expect the `getName` to work? You can't `getName` a `string`.

Comment: So just call `Obama.getName()`. What's the problem? A string is not something you can `getName`d.

Comment: @user202729 How do people use cin>>(insert string here) to call on a (insert string here).getName(); then? You have to be able to get the name from a user input at some point so how do people do that using a string if something is already declared. Lets say "John" is already in the data base. How will the user be able to input something into the console and that input be converted into a string which will be used right before the .getName();

Comment: @user202729 Thank you, but how do people use strings that are imputed by users to call upon Obama? Say they already declared it and want to access his information. Wouldn't you use a cin>> and a string to get the user input? Thank you again.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton It's completely unclear what you are asking. What has `std::cin` to do with that now? What database are you talking about?

Comment: @MatthewHamilton `std::string` doesn't have a method named `getName`. Hence, people aren't using it. It's still unclear, what do you expect your `getName` to do. Here's a link to the [documentation of `std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), with all available methods listed, since it is obvious you couldn't find on your own.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton I hope this question gets closed and deleted soon. That's nothing useful for anyone who will research in future about an unclear problem.

Comment: @TheDude I can delete the question if you would recommend that. It was helpful to me and I learned I bit, I just wish I could have asked this in a more clear way.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton No you can't delete the question anymore, since it has upvoted answers now.

Comment: @TheDude I tried rewording the question. Hopefully it is slightly more comprehendible.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton No, there's no improvement with your edit. I still don't get what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @TheDude I will work on how I format questions on here. I just noticed I made a big mistake in the code above that prob confused many people. I think I fixed it though. I got a little question ban, but I learned from it so thats good c: "It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just do your best to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 2 days!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way in C++ to use a string to look up a variable of the same name in C++.

What you have to do is create the appropriate data structure for yourself. One way to do that would be to use a `map`.

```
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, Enemy> my_map;
...
Enemy trump("Trump", 250, 30);
my_map["Trump"] = trump;
...
std::string name = ...;
Enemy some_enemy = my_map[name];
```

Comment: ... did you understand the question? _wait for OP reaction_

Comment: @user202729 I took a fair guess, the OP seems a bit incoherent.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question. I am surprised you simply can not  use a user imputed string to look up a variable of the same name. I gave you an upvote.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton It's the nature of C++, variable names chosen by the programmer don't exist in the compiled program and so aren't accessible at run time. This is done for efficiency reasons, but other languages do things differently.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton Wait, what please??

Comment: It states that votes cast by someone with less the 15 rep are recorded but not publicly displayed.

Comment: @john That makes sense. I am starting too see why I can not just simply use a string in front of .getName I am a Junior majoring in CS and this is my first class on C++. I am a little ahead on the lessons on Classes, but now I see I am a far bit away from being able to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish, so I will wait till I have finished the course. I have nothing against Obama I am trying to get my brother to switch to CS so I make little games for him to play and modify hoping he will take a liking to the idea of CS. I won't be able to present this to my brother by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the instances by name as a static data member in a map for example. But there should be better ways to do it depending on the complete design of your program. But since you didn't provide all the context I'm just going to show a generic example. With some issues like non thread safety, missing null checks, not dealing with duplicates, etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Enemy{
    public:
    std::string m_name;
    int m_hp;
    int m_dmg;
    static std::map<std::string,Enemy*> s_instances;

    Enemy(const std::string& name, int hp, int dmg)
    : m_name(name),
      m_hp(hp),
      m_dmg(dmg)
    {
        s_instances[name] = this;
    }
    ~Enemy()
    {
        s_instances.erase(m_name);
    }

    const std::string& getName() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    static Enemy* getInstanceByName(const std::string& name)
    {
        Enemy* result = nullptr;
        auto iter = s_instances.find(name);
        if(iter!=s_instances.end()) result = iter->second;
        return result;
    }

};

std::map<std::string,Enemy*> Enemy::s_instances;

void doStuff()
{
    Enemy* instance = Enemy::getInstanceByName("Ork");
    std::cout << instance->getName();
}

int main() {
    Enemy ork("Ork",300,20);
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user202729 I don't care. The dude tried to clarify in the comments and I don't know how you could interpret his question any other way

Comment: @user202729 the non-gender specific person or entity asking the the question

Comment: @user202729 I still can't make sense from all that.

Comment: Just say "the OP" (original poster (SE abbreviated terms)).

Comment: Wow this looks interesting. I have no idea what #include <map> does, but I will have to read up on this.

Comment: std::map<std::string,Enemy*> Enemy::s_instances; <----- That looks super cool. I will try that as well. I have never used maps before.

Comment: @MatthewHamilton Here's some good resource to read up: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: @PeterT It is refreshing and humbling looking back on this question now that I have a BS in Computer Science.